# AMF class mapping not working

Tags: apache-flex, object, types, amfphp, zend-amf

I am building an application using Flex 4.5 and Zend_AMF as my AMF endpoint.

I would like to map a class called CRequest in PHP to a class called Request in Flex.

This is my php class:

```
<?php
namespace app\web;

class CRequest{
   public $_explicitType = 'com.site.remote.Request';

   public $stuff1;

   public $stuff2;

}
```

This is the actionscript class: com.site.remote.Request

```
package com.dreamatique.remoting
{
    [Bindable]
    [RemoteClass(alias="com.site.remote.Request")]
    public class Request
    {

        public var stuff1:String;

        public var stuff2:String;

        public function Request()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

As a test, I have made the endpoint return an instance of `CRequest` from the PHP side, no matter what the request.

I am then making a remote object call like this:

```
var remoteObject:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject();
remoteObject.endpoint = "http://localhost/to/my/amf/endpoint";
remoteObject.showBusyCursor = true;
remoteObject.source = 'testing';
var op:AbstractOperation = remoteObject.getOperation(null);
op.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, result);
op.send();

public static function result(event:ResultEvent):void{

    trace(event.result);
    trace(Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(event.result))));
    Alert.show(event.result.toString());

}
```

The problem is that the result comes back typed as `ObjectProxy` and not `Request`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you have at least one reference to the class somewhere in your codebase.

This is a common trap, especially when first developing a remote call, and before you've actually consumed the type in any code anywhere.

If the class is not referenced, it's not compiled in, and therefore, doesn't get registered.

Often, during early development, I'll end up creating a `StaticLinker` class:

```
public class StaticLinks
{
    private var request:Request;
}
```

Then reference this in my application:

```
<s:Script>
   var linker:StaticLinks;
</s:Script>
```

BTW - you're correct in your earlier assumption:  If you have annotated the class as a `[RemoteObject]`, you're not required to call `registerClass()`.

Comment: This was it! After playing around, I found that the class will get typed if I created an instance of it `var testing:Request;`!

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to register the class?

```
import flash.net.registerClassAlias;

flash.net.registerClassAlias("com.site.remote.Request", Request);
```

Comment: From what I have read (http://www.roboncode.com/articles/144) and other blog posts, `registerClassAlias` isn't necessary if I am using the flex framework, but I could be wrong. While the objects come back typed as `Request` if I use `registerClassAlias`, the odd thing is that if I set `flash.net.registerClassAlias("asdfsomegibberish", Request);` the object still comes back typed as request.