# Flex is deserializing generic objects from Zend AMF instead of strictly typed objects

Tags: php, apache-flex, deserialization, amf, zend-amf

I'm using Zend AMF to send my remote objects to Flex.

I've defined a `Constant` class and created `getASClassName()` method. Then I've created Action script class in flex.

Objects are send successfully, but they are deserialized to generic `Objects` in Flex instead of specific ones.

EDIT: On network monitor in Flex I can see that AMF value is set to `com.my.project.valueobjects.Constant`. Although array from `event.result` contains `Objects`.

What am I doing wrong?

Php declaration of class:

```
<?php
namespace Project\Entity;

class Constant
{
    public $id;

    public $name;

    public  $description;

    public $value;

    public function getASClassName(){
        return 'com.my.project.valueobjects.Constant';
    }
}
```

Class definition in flex:

```
package com.my.project.valueobjects{

    [Bindable]
    [RemoteClass(alias="Constant")]
    public class Constant{
        public var id:Number;
        public var name:String;
        public var description:String;
        public var value:String;
    }
```

Part of code handling Amf in php:

```
$server = new Zend_Amf_Server();
$server = $server->setClass("AmfService");
$server->setClassMap("com.my.project.valueobjects.Constant", "Constant");
```

Array of objects from php (dump made using `print_r`):

```
[04-Mar-2012 14:23:08] Array
(
    [0] => Project\Entity\Constant Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => name
            [description] => desc
            [value] => 5
            [_explicitType] => com.my.project.valueobjects.Constant
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another self-answer in the area of Flex/PHP remoting.

Solution was pretty easy - I needed to change `com.my.project.valueobjects.Constant` to `Constant` in PHP side and it was everything.

Hope this helps someone in the future.